# Callback to activity from other class

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-activity, callback

I have  `Activity` class, `Controller` class (normal java class use to control number of activity) and `BusinessEngine` class (normal java class use to process data).

When I need to do some calculation from activity, `Activity` will call `Controller` and `Controller` will call `BusinessEngine` to do the calculation. When `BusinessEngine` done with the calculation, it will pass the value back to `Controller` and finally let the activity know the calculation is complete.

The problem is how I callback `Activity` from `Controller` class? Or pass any data to `Activity` and notify it the data has been change?

Answer (score 1):

Any "long" running tasks must be performed in a background thread.  I'm not sure if your currently doing this for your task, so just in case your not, there are a couple of ways to do this.  The first is to simply use a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), the second is to create your own instance of [AbstractExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html) (AsyncTask uses [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)) and use that to post [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [Callables](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) to.  The later way may save you a lot of re factoring depending on your code base.

Assuming you're now running the task in a background thread, it's necessary to perform your UI updates on the UI thread.  There are again a couple of ways to do this.  One method is to post a runnable to the method [Activity#runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29), the second is to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) which has previously been created on the UI thread (which Activity#runOnUiThread does behind the scenes).

So, assume your Activity has a method #postResults(final Object o), and your controller has the method #doSomething(final Activity activity).

Your activity would look something like this.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Controller controller = ....
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    private void startTask() {  
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                c.doSomething(MyActivity.this);
            }
        }
        service.submit(r);           
    }

    public void postResults(final Object o) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Update your UI here
            }
        }
        runOnUiThread(r)    
    }

}
```

and your controller

```
public class Controller {

    public void doSomething(final Activity activity) {
        // Perform some long running task here
        activity.postResults(someObject);       
    }
}
```

Obviously this example could be tidied up (for example passing a interface to doSomething rather than the Activity), but hopefully it should be enough to understand what you need to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for the controller to call you Activity? Normally, your Activity must call the controller via its methods and directly get results from them:

```
// Code in your Activity
result = controller.doSomething(args);
```

Comment: If do as you suggest then my activity will freeze until doSomething is complete, even if I put a thread on doSomething; then I won't know when is result useable since I don't have callback to notify me it's ready to use.

Comment: If your method takes a lot of time to execute, then you can use AsyncTask in your Activity to do the job: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

try using a android AsyncTask, if your method takes a long time to process. [example](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Add your classes to an Async task or if you're calling the classes and passing them from one class to the other.I would say to use static class. And provide some code so we can know how you are passing your data.

If not use general methods to call the superclass or the subclass.

My answer is a bit abstract as information is less.